# How do I stop Visual Studio 2010 from downloading large files when connected through FTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Here is the scenario.  I connect to my server from a random computer to do a couple of updates through FTP in Visual Studio 2010.  I open up the page I wanted to edit which has links to several very large files.  It seems the intellisense goes out to look for these files.  Visual Studio will then be stuck trying to find these very large files and I have to wait forever just to make a small change on a page.  I have been looking for option to turn this feature off, but I'm not sure exactly where I should be looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps you

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151126015223/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/zainnab/archive/2010/05/01/how-to-turn-off-automatic-intellisense-vstipedit0054.aspx)
​​​​